# Grab popup.html shown by Google Translate Chrome Extension using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-translate

I am creating a chrome extension which supposed to grab **google translate** chrome extension html response , using javascript.

This grabber extension should wait until that popup become visible.

But when I use GetElementbyID , the result is null.

```
document.getElementById("bubble-content");
```

I know it is because the page source had downloaded before the javascript has worked.
But can I even fetch this pop up in a way?

I thank you if you say How ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows it's inside ShadowDOM so you can't get it directly. Moreover it's `closed` so you'll have to hook the original attachShadow method in [page context](/a/9517879). Not rocket science, but quite a few advanced concepts anyway, still should be totally doable.

Comment: @wOxxOm I read the link you mentioned , but yet I have no idea how can I fetch that "bubble-content" , do you have any idea ? Thank You

Comment: See [this extension](https://github.com/tophf/XRayStyler/tree/shadow-targeting/content) for an example of hooking attachShadow in page context.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer ! , I will check that out.